# prevent automatically page scroll up when using jquery fadein/out founction on fixed position div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a web page and I want to make a div that appears on the right side of screen by click a button (both div and button have fixed position)
I made it appear by using jQuery fadein/out

it works fine but when I click the button, the page slides to top automatically

htmlCode:

```
<div class="fixedDiv">
    <div class="fixedDiv liveSupportFrame" style="background: #f8aa00;display: none" id="lsf">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#d8d6d6;">
        ............
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="btn btn-warning sideBtn" onclick="showOrHideLiveSupport();" role="button" href="#">FAQ</a>
```

CSS code:

```
.fixedDiv{
position: fixed;
bottom: 25%;
right: 0em;
}
.fixedDiv .liveSupportFrame{
margin-right: 2em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
font-size:1.6vw;
bottom: 30%;
}
```

JS code:

```
        var isLsfOpen = 0;
    function showOrHideLiveSupport() {
       if(!isLsfOpen){
           showLiveSupport()
       }
       else{
           hideLiveSupport()
       }
    }
    function showLiveSupport() {
        $('#lsf').fadeIn();

        isLsfOpen=true;
    }
    function hideLiveSupport() {
        $('#lsf').fadeOut();
        isLsfOpen=false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of `href="#"`. Use `event.preventDefault();` in your handler.